# picoLisp language: onOff question

Tags: lisp, picolisp

**This question is really moot, I think I must have hit a bug in my program or something. If you are still looking for [PicoLisp](http://picolisp.com/) and onOff behaviour, look [here](http://www.software-lab.de/doc/refO.html#onOff).**

---

---

---

<strike>is this supposed to happen?</strike>

```
: (show NIL)
NIL NIL
-> NIL
: (onOff)
-> T
: (show NIL)
T T
-> T
: (=T NIL)
-> T
: 

(onOff sym ..) -> flg

Logical negates the VAL's of all argument symbols sym. Returns the
new value of the last symbol.
```

- Should not the symbol names be passed explicitly?
- Why does it return value of the last symbol?

Comment: Is `=T` a typo, or do you actually have an operator of that name?

Comment: There actually is such an operator in picolisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a red herring, there was no bug. Sorry, [HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=962795) wrong call. Also, it is now under the MIT (X11) license, the most liberal of open source licenses.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the PicoLisp implementation with the `onOff` **macro**.

[The parameters of the `onOff` function are](http://www.software-lab.de/refO.html#onOff): `(onOff var ..) -> flg`

It takes a *var* and many more variables and logically negates them (true becomes false, false becomes true). I'm willing to bet that the `onOff` **macro** takes a single list of arguments. Which means that if NO arguments are given to it, that list of arguments is empty which means the symbol given to the function is NIL.

**Macro** is bolded because that's where the problem lies. Using a macro makes it so you can pass the symbols to it without quoting. So the `onOff` macro is generating incorrect code.

Comment: This answer is obsolete at best.